# Pourquoi écrit-on "en tout cas" et non "en tous cas" ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, accord, tout-tous

Dans un commentaire, j'ai écrit spontanément "en tout cas",
puis, en me relisant, je me suis demandé 
si ce ne serait pas plutôt "en tous cas".
Une brève recherche rapide m'a donné la réponse : 
je n'avais pas fait de faute.

Cependant, aucune explication ne me semble ni claire ni convaincante.
Pour moi, il aurait été plus logique de mettre tout au pluriel,
puisqu'il ne s'agit pas simplement d'un cas que nous prendrions dans son ensemble ("dans tout le cas"),
mais plutôt de plusieurs cas que l'on rassemble ("dans tous les cas"),
par exemple :

> Est-ce que nous allons à gauche ou à droite ? En tout cas, dépêchons-nous !

Donc, quelqu'un a-t-il une explication ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Là c'est le genre de question qu'on se pose après avoir manqué d'y remarquer rien de difficile pendant toute sa vie. ;)

Étant une question de ce genre, on s'attendrait peut-être à ce que la réponse soit insatisfaisante, mais heureusement, le dictionnaire nous expliquera tout.

Dans [l'article du Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout), l'acception la plus pertinente est celle-ci :

> **TOUT**, **TOUTE**, **TOUS**, **TOUTES**, adj. indéf. et pron. indéf.
>   
> **I.** − Adj. indéf.
>   
> **C.** − ***Au sing.*** [Marque l'idée de distributivité exhaustive, « intensionnelle » et virtualisante (**dans ce sens, il est proche de chaque**)]

Le voilà en un mot. Et pour terminer notre quête, « C. » est aussi subdivisé :

> **2.** [Après prép., formant des loc. adj. ou des loc. adv.]

C'est sous ce titre qu'on retrouve *en tout cas*.

Si tu cherches cette définition dans l'article tu trouveras quelques remarques très éclairantes dont la troisième commence ainsi :

> **3.** *Tout* est virtualisant, en ce sens qu'il opère sur une classe virtuelle. C'est en cela qu'il s'oppose à *chaque*, qui suppose une classe fermée, actuelle si l'on préfère. Que l'on compare les deux énoncés *Chaque candidat aura accès à son dossier* et *Tout candidat aura accès à son dossier*. Dans le premier cas, on pose qu'il y a un nombre donné de candidats; ce qui est dit est vrai de chacun d'eux. Dans le second, ce qui est dit est vrai de quelque candidat que ce soit, sans qu'on se prononce sur leur existence effective dans une situation déterminée. [...]

On dirait qu'*en tout cas* veut donc dire « dans n'importe quel cas, quoi que ce soit, bien que les cas ne soient pas énumérés ». (Je n'essaierai pas de traiter du choix de préposition ici.)

*En tous cas* est aussi admissible, mais le sens diffère un peu peut-être. Comme l'observe l'auteure de la grammaire qu'a citée Laure ci-dessous, dans certains cas

> *TOUT* signifie *n'importe lequel*, *chaque* et on emploie le singulier [... tandis que] si on considère **l'ensemble** ou si la logique l'exige, *TOUT* et le nom qui suit sont au pluriel.

---

Quant à [l'étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tout), *tout* comme pronom semble être plus ancien, mais l'acception qu'on vient de repérer existe elle aussi depuis un millénaire :

> **B.** Sing.
>   
> **1.** valeur de qualificatif; signifie l'intégralité d'une notion **a)** fin x<sup>e</sup> masc. tot per ver « en toute vérité » (*Passion*, 272); *ca* 1100 fém. (*Roland*, 391: Seit ki l'ociet, **tute** pais puis avriumes); [...]

Il serait intéressant de tracer la « transformation » de pronom en article au cours des siècles, mais suffit-ce pour l'instant de constater qu'il n'y en a rien de surprenant du point de vue sémantique.

Comment: Tu peux voir aussi le TLF à cas....  et Littré à cas. Je n'ai pas retrouvé dans Grevisse mais explication claire aussi dans cette [grammaire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-uxiw3SSnDsC&pg=PT97&lpg=PT97&dq=%22en+tous+cas%22+ou+%22en+tout+cas%22&source=bl&ots=SLwbmVnOVy&sig=NTUMuRWxS8M727Zt1ycFmUcvbVY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv-JOq6MzVAhULalAKHZ2bAsg4HhDoAQg6MAM#v=onepage&q=%22en%20tous%20cas%22%20ou%20%22en%20tout%20cas%22&f=false).

Comment: @Distic Tout à fait ! C'est corrigé. Laure : Merci, je rajoute cette note sur l'admissibilité du pluriel.